# "Object required" when saving an email draft in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm having issues saving a draft of a response to emails:

```
Dim fwdItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set fwdItem = item.ReplyAll
fwdItem.HTMLBody = "Looks Good." & vbCrLf & fwdItem.HTMLBody
fwdItem.SaveAs "C:\test.msg"
```

When it hits the `"Save as"` line, it gives me an Object Required error, but if it's instead `fwdItem.Display`, it works fine.

MSDN told me that it's usually due to using an variant as opposed to explicitly typing an object, but that's not what's going on here.

Comment: I testedwith Set fwdItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem.ReplyAll  in 2010. Saves whether or not I display just before SaveAs. Maybe you will be satisfied with adding Display. Since you declare Outlook.Mailitem are you calling Outlook from another application? You may be able to help someone reproduce the behaviour with a complete example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's not being called from another application - outlook is set to run the script that contains this line on every mail I receive.

The "Outlook" being referenced is the outlook namespace, not a reference to an object of the application's type.

Answer (score 0):

How are you selecting the Mail Item?

This  works on Outlook 2010

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem

    Set Item = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Debug.Print Item

    Set Item = Item.ReplyAll
    Debug.Print Item

    Item.HTMLBody = "Looks Good." & vbCrLf & Item.HTMLBody
    Item.SaveAs ("C:\Temp\test.msg"), olMsg

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly specify the type (olMsg or olMsgUnicode when calling SaveAs.

Also do not concatenate two HTML strings - they must be merged.